# What is MySql workbench and for what purpose we use it?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, mysql-workbench

I'm a student i know Java, servlet and learning JSP at this moment but i found that some developers use `MySql Workbench`. may i know Why do we use it can you explain me in briefly, i'm using Intellij IDE but that can support MySql too, and can be handled queries language but what's the reason behind that developers prefers MySql Workbench ? and should i move on with MySql Workbench?

Pls someone explain me in briefly?

Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: [What is MySQL Workbench?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench)

Comment: And why mostly developer prefer it?

Comment: Because different tools are better suited for different tasks.

Comment: Can it be handled hundred tables with one database easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql Workbench is an UI for Mysql

It means you can access to your database from a visual interface.

You can perform run queries, create databases, modify tables, create users and everything from there.

In recent versions, you are also able to check your db performance

Comment: Can it be handled hundred of tables with one database easily?

Comment: This is the UI developed and suggested for mysql. Your tables are displayed on the left side, and yes, it can.

Comment: Thansk man, i'll accpet your answer after 5 minutes :)